# ConversationalRetrievalChain raising KeyError

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, langchain, large-language-model

I am implementing RAG on a Gemma-2B-it model using langchain's HuggingFaceEmbeddings and ConversationalRetrievalChain.

When running:

```
chat_history = []
question = "My prompt"
result = qa.invoke({"question": question, "chat_history": chat_history})
```

I get

```
    276 
    277                 if self.pipeline.task == "text-generation":
--> 278                     text = response["generated_text"]
    279                 elif self.pipeline.task == "text2text-generation":
    280                     text = response["generated_text"]

KeyError: 'generated_text'
```

I don't understand why this is happening. It used to work and, today, it just stopped working. I have also tried using `qa.run` instead of `invoke` but it still raises the same exception.

I have tried changing models, devices but nothing fixes it.

Comment: @AhmetBirim I did not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `transformers.pipeline`, then make sure that this `return_tensors='pt'` parameter is not passed.